# Why are triangular prisms used to demonstrate dispersion of light? Wouldn't a rectangular slab also work?

Tags: optics, refraction

Using a triangular glass prism to disperse white light into a rainbow works because different wavelengths/colours of light have different refractive indices in glass, doesn't it?

The different refractive indices apply regardless of the shape of the glass. Therefore, wouldn't a simple rectangular slab of glass also disperse white light? The different wavelengths would be differently refracted and emerge separated from the other end.

Why is a triangular prism always used to demonstrate dispersion? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question and the link therein? [Refraction of white light through a glass slab: what does it actually look like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/198043/refraction-of-white-light-through-a-glass-slab-what-does-it-actually-look-like)

Comment: because it is more visible, no pun intended, if you also change the paths traveled by the bundle of rays being dispersed in angle.

Comment: thank you Farcher. So the dispersion does occur but the dispersed rays emerge parallel to each other, so it is harder to observe?